# deinterlacing with no interpolation kernel

Tags: video, graphics, opencl, gpgpu, video-processing

I am looking into OpenCL kernels for a specific real-time deinterlacing problem. I have **frames (RGB, 720*480*3)** which are composed of **4 interlaced fields**. So I am trying to **deinterlace** to the original fields *G* of dimension (*width*/4)*(*height*/4), using the following equation:

*G_i = 1/4( f(x', y') + f(x' + 1, y') + f(x' + 2, y') + f(x' + 3, y') )*

where *i = 0, 1, 2, 3*

and *(x', y') = (4x, 4y + i)*

The resulting field *G_i* would therefore have 1/16th of the pixels of the frame, and ultimately I am planning to use the deinterlaced fields separately.

Here is what I have achieved so far, but I have been struggling for quite a time, and I am not quite there. Could someone please help? I think I would  need a 4-wide stride to traverse the flattened frame?

## The call to the OpenCL program (in PyOpenCL):

```
# call limiting the global work space to 1/16th of the frame
# outputting to array of 1/16th the size
    self.program.deinterlace(self.queue, (self.dim[0]/self.n, self.dim[1]/self.n),
                             None,
                             self.frame_buf, self.dest_buf,
                             np.int32(self.dim[1]),
                             np.int32(self.dim[2]))
    result = np.empty((self.dim[0]/self.n, self.dim[1]/self.n, 3),
                      dtype=np.uint8)
    cl.enqueue_copy(self.queue, result, self.dest_buf).wait()
```

## The OpenCL kernel:

```
__kernel void deinterlace(

        __global const uchar *a,
        __global uchar *c,
        const int width,
        const int channels
    )
    {
        int rowid = get_global_id(0);
        int colid = get_global_id(1);

        int ncols = width;
        int nchan = channels;

        int index = rowid * 4 * ncols * 4 * nchan + colid * 4 * nchan;
        int newindex = rowid * ncols * nchan + colid * nchan;
        c[newindex + 0] = a[index + 0];
        c[newindex + 1] = a[index + 1];
        c[newindex + 2] = a[index + 2];
    }
```

## The frame:

[image: base frame]

## The result:

[image: resulting field 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, so I had just forgotten to scale down the iteration bounds...

the call to the OpenCL program should be:

```
# call limiting the global work space to 1/16th of the frame
# outputting to array of 1/16th the size
    self.program.deinterlace(self.queue, (self.dim[0]/self.n, self.dim[1]/self.n),
                             None,
                             self.frame_buf, self.dest_buf,
                             np.int32(self.dim[1]/self.n),
                             np.int32(self.dim[2]))
    result = np.empty((self.dim[0]/self.n, self.dim[1]/self.n, 3),
                      dtype=np.uint8)
    cl.enqueue_copy(self.queue, result, self.dest_buf).wait()
```

Comment: So, fixed? Good! :D But I still don't understand what you are doing.... it looks like it is not "deinterlace" but something different.